# How to test two-way binding with directive's isolateScope in jasmine+angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I want to test that parent scope gets new value after directive changed it, but for some reason it does not work.

This is my directive

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        template: 'just a template',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'model' : '=myDirective'
        }, 
        link: function postLink( scope ){
            scope.changeModelValue = function( value ){
                scope.model = value;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is my test

```
describe('the test', function(){

    var scope, isolateScope, element;

    var reset = function(){
        scope = null;
        isolateScope = null;
        element = null;
    };

    beforeEach( inject(function( $rootScope ){
        scope = $rootScope.new();
        reset();
    }));

    var setup = inject(function( $compile ){
        element = angular.element('<div my-directive="item"></div>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        isolateScope = element.children().scope();
    });

    it('should work', inject(function( $timeout ){
        scope.item = null; 
        setup();
        expect(typeof(isolateScope.changeModelValue)).toBe('function'); // works!
        isolateScope.changeModelValue('new value');
        expect(isolateScope.model).toBe('new value'); // works!

        // tried all the of this - but didn't help..
        waitsFor(function(){
            try{ $timeout.flush(); } catch (e) { }
            try{ scope.$digest.flush(); } catch (e) { }
            try{ isolateScope.$digest(); } catch (e) { }

            return scope.reportLesson !== null;
        });

        runs(function(){
            expect(scope.item).toBe('new value'); //fails!!
        });

    }));
});
```

As you can see I tried some flushing and such, thinking perhaps there's some async actions that need to happen in order for it to work, but it didn't help.

The test reaches timeout on the waitsFor.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `$digest` and `$timeout.flush` will not affect the binding.

In order to make it work, I had to call `isolateScope.$apply()`. I would still like to have an explanation for this.

Comment: `$digest` fires watches in that scope. `$apply` runs `$digest` on `$rootScope` ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#pseudo-code-of-apply-)). You could also do `scope.$digest()` or `scope.$apply()` - both should work as well

Comment: wholly effff i wasted too much time on this. at least there's donuts in the office today.

Answer (score -1):

Uh I might be wrong but it looks like the way you're doing the binding there doesn't make sense.

```
// 2-way-bind the value of 'model' in this scope to the myDirective attribute in the parent scope
scope: {
    'model' : '=myDirective'
},
```

If that were '=item' instead then that makes sense given what you want, so try that.

Another thing you are doing which is a bit odd:

```
// Give my directive an attribute which is the 'item' element from the scope
element = angular.element('<div my-directive="item"></div>');
```

So that's a bit weird, read this SO answer: [AngularJS Directive Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710678/angularjs-directive-value)

You're overloading your directive declaration with an attribute, and you're mixing up scope variables with attributes (which can be accessed through your link function, but not what you're doing).

Edit:

As a final note, you should probably trust AngularJS is doing the binding correctly. It is time consuming to write these kind of tests and you should focus on program logic instead.

Comment: Are you familiar with [isolate scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)? This is what he is doing

Comment: Are you familiar with them? Because that is not what he is doing. He's trying to use a two-way binding on the parent scope (with '=') and confusing that with an attribute binding. You didn't read his question or my answer and told him off about practice rather than trying to help him understand, then downvoted me. Good job.

Comment: If I made a mistake, I'll take it back, but where do you see him confusing this with an attribute binding? Here's doing normal two-way binding ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MxRlyBB9UpTZ3Y4mpRWU?p=preview) of his example that you said was "odd")